# Show all data when no items are marked

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

In Spotfire, is there a way to write a script that changes the default setting of "Empty Visualization" when no items are marked? I have a button that changes the chart from line to bar (and then back again) but since I am using a heat map to mark values the charts default show no data until I select on of thsoe values in the heatmap.

Comment: So you want to select all when you really have none selected, since this visualization is a details visualization of another chart?

Comment: Yes, essentially. I have a second chart that is limited by the markings from the first chart. Normally I get around this by going into the properties of that chart and under data there is a drop down menu that gives you 3 options: One is to show an empty chart, show all data, or show a message. The default seems to be show an empty chart. I am using a button to toggle between 2 chart types and it resets to the default when toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the chart property you're looking for is called [`LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api/Index.aspx) and accepts a [`LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api/?topic=html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior.htm) value. here's an example you could put on a button:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart

v = visualization_parameter.As[BarChart]()

v.Data.LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior = LimitingMarkingsEmptyBehavior.ShowAll
```

Comment: Niko crushing as usual

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, thank you both for the help! (I upvoted but it won't show)

Comment: @B_H glad it worked for you! :) could you please accept the answer as correct?

Comment: @scsimon I do what I can. :D

Comment: Hey Niko check the bounty tab for Spotfire